# Converting a shell command with $(...) for Python subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python-3.x, shell

I have a docker command that works from terminal and gives expected result.

Now I need to re-write this script into python. Whenever trying to run python, the following error comes up:
    unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a
    See 'docker logs --help'.

Below is the command. I have been trying to play with a list array but nothing seems to be working.

Original command in terminal:

```
docker logs $(docker ps -a -f status=exited| grep -w "dev"| awk '{print $1}')
```

Python equivalent:

```
 output = subprocess.Popen([
    "docker",
    "logs",
    "$(docker",
    "ps",
    "-a",
    "-f",
    "status=exited",
    "|",
    "grep",
    "-w",
    "'dev'",
    "|",
    "awk",
    "'{print $1}'"
])
```

Comment: That's not how you convert the command, subprocess will *quote* those arguments so e.g. `"$(docker"` will be a positional argument to `docker logs`, not start of another command whose result will be interpolated into the args. You don't need to do this all in one go! Split it up into separate steps.

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that subprocess quotes the arguments -- subprocess *isn't running a shell at all*, so shell quoting is a meaningless concept. That said, to make a shell do the same thing this code does would indeed involve quoting, like `'docker' 'logs' '$(docker' 'ps' '-a' '-f' 'status=exited' '|' 'grep' '-w' "'dev'" '|' 'awk' "'{print $1}'"`, which (if run in bash) would fail with the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In bash $(...) is run as another process and the output is substituted in its place. Everything inside is one argument from the interpreter's perspective.

You will need to run `docker ps -a -f status=exited| grep -w "dev"| awk '{print $1}'` first and use its output as an argument to `docker logs ...`.

However, with python you don't need pipe through grep and awk, you can use list comprehensions to do mapping and filtering:

```
import subprocess
containers = subprocess.Popen(["docker", "ps", "-a", "-f", "status=exited"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
lines = [l.decode('utf-8') for l in containers.stdout.readlines()] # Convert bytes to strings
filtered = [line for line in lines if 'dev' in line] # Keep only lines with keyword
ids = [l.split()[0] for l in filtered]               # Select first column


for i in ids:
    print(">>>> Logs for " + i)
    subprocess.call(['docker', 'logs', i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original bash code isn't running one command -- it's running four!

- First, it runs a pipeline consisting of three commands, with the stdout of each connected to the stdin of the next:

  - `['docker', 'ps', '-a', '-f', 'status=exited']`
  - `['grep', '-w', 'dev']`
  - `['awk', '{print $1}']`
- Second, it uses the output of the last piece of that pipeline (the `awk` command) to construct a final `docker logs` command:

  - `['docker', 'logs'] + shlex.split(awk_pipeline_output)` (roughly; because you didn't properly quote, it'll also evaluate each word of that `split` result as a glob expression).

---

So, if you really wanted to convert that code to Python, leaving it otherwise exactly-as-written, it would look like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import shlex

p1 = Popen(['docker', 'ps', '-a', '-f', 'status=exited'], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['grep', '-w', 'dev'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p3 = Popen(['awk', '{print $1}'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.stdout.close()
pipeline_output, _ = p3.communicate()

p4 = Popen(['docker', 'logs'] + shlex.split(pipeline_outlet))
```